# Get data from webservice and bind to autotextview without freezing UI

Tags: android, data-binding, startup, freeze

I am stuck with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

In onCreate method of MainActivity, I call list of ingredients from a web service using soap and bind them to autotextview. Unfortunately, list of ingredient variable always null before binding since it couldn't retrieve faster than processor jumps to next line.

Could anybody propose me a method to overcome this problem without freezing UI at startup time?

---- Edit----

Inside Main Activity onCreate

```
      globalVars = (MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext();//requested data will be stored in global variables.
      populateSpinners(); // get spinner data using CallSoap
      getIngredients(); // get ingredient names for autotextview using CallSoap

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,globalVars.ingredientTitles); 
     // globalVars.ingredientTitles be initialized in onPostExecute of Caller class.
      AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
      autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is populatespinners (in the same way it executes getIngredients)

```
private void populateSpinners(){
    try
    {
        Caller c=new Caller(this.getApplicationContext());
        c.functionName = "getDropDownData";
        c.vil = null;
        c.execute();

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "populateSpinners: "+ex.getMessage(),ex );
    }
}
```

here is caller which extends AsyncTask

```
     public CallSoap cs;
        public List<variableInfo> vil;
        public String functionName;

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String response;
                try{
                    cs=new CallSoap();
                    String resp=cs.CallService(functionName,vil);
                    response=resp;
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    response=ex.toString();
                }
                return response;
               }

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if(functionName == "getDropDownData")
            {
               //here initializes globalVars
            }
        }
```

here is CallSoap Class- service call

```
public String CallService(String functionName, List<variableInfo> variables) {
        OPERATION_NAME = functionName;
        SOAP_ADDRESS = HOST_ADDRESS + ASMX_NAME;
        WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://bulyapye.com/";
        SOAP_ACTION = WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE + functionName;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
        if (variables != null) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < variables.size(); i++) {
                PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                pi.setName(variables.get(i).name);
                pi.setValue(toObject(variables.get(i).type, variables.get(i).value));
                pi.setType(variables.get(i).type);
                request.addProperty(pi);
            }
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response = null;
        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            response = exception.toString();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an asynchronous function to call the webservice (using listener or [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)). Here a sample using listener:

```
interface SoapGetterListener {
     public success(String data);
     public error(Exception e);
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SoapGetterListener {
      ...
      globalVars = (MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext();//requested data will be stored in global variables.
      populateSpinners(this); // get spinner data using CallSoap
      getIngredients(this); // get ingredient names for autotextview using CallSoap
      ...
    public success(String data) {
         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data); 
         AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
         autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    ...
}


// Pass SoapGetterListener to CallSoap constructor so you can
// use in onPostExecute()
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(functionName == "getDropDownData")
           listener.success(result)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to make the main thread to wait until another thread returns the request because the request data will be used at the next line. It will be source of a spinner. Could you propose a method, a working example?

Comment: If you post the relevant part of your code I could propose a modification.